# Trouble properly setting up descriptor sets for multiple models in Vulkan

Tags: graphics, vulkan, low-level

I'm having a problem trying to implement multiple models in Vulkan. I used the official Vulkan tutorial to set up most of the boilerplate code, then the rest is custom. At the moment, I am able to get one model to render perfectly, while the other identical model renders in about 60% of frames and doesn't render at all in others, as shown in the gif: [Engine output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77fms.gif)

I've tried changing many things to fix it, but I can't pinpoint what is causing the issue. Any help would be appreciated wholly. I'm attaching the code snippets I think most relevant but I can include more if it helps solve the issue.

CreateCommandBuffers():

```
...
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offsets);
vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffers[i], indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);

vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSets[i], 0, nullptr); //COMEBACKTO

vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], models[0].getModelIndicesSize(), 1, 0, 0, 0);

vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSets[i + 1], 0, nullptr);
vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], models[0].getModelIndicesSize(), 1, 0, 0, 0);
...
```

createDescriptorSets():

```
    std::vector<VkDescriptorSetLayout> layouts(swapChainImages.size() * models.size(), descriptorSetLayout);
    VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo allocInfo{};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.descriptorPool = descriptorPool;
    allocInfo.descriptorSetCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(swapChainImages.size() * models.size());
    allocInfo.pSetLayouts = layouts.data();

    descriptorSets.resize(swapChainImages.size() * models.size());
    if (vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &allocInfo, descriptorSets.data()) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate descriptor sets!");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < swapChainImages.size(); i++) {
        std::vector<VkWriteDescriptorSet> descWrites;
        descWrites.resize(models.size() * 2);

        for (int j = 0; j < models.size(); j++) {
            VkDescriptorBufferInfo bufferInfo{};
            bufferInfo.offset = 0;
            bufferInfo.range = sizeof(UniformBufferObject);
            //bufferInfo.buffer = uniformBuffers[i];
            bufferInfo.buffer = uniformBuffers[j + (i * (models.size() - 1))];

            VkDescriptorImageInfo imageInfo{};
            imageInfo.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
            imageInfo.imageView = textureImageView; //set these up
            imageInfo.sampler = textureSampler; //set these up

            int tmp = j * 2;
            int tmp1 = tmp + 1;

            descWrites[tmp].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
            descWrites[tmp].dstSet = descriptorSets[j + (i * (models.size() - 1))];
            descWrites[tmp].dstBinding = 0;
            descWrites[tmp].dstArrayElement = 0;
            descWrites[tmp].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
            descWrites[tmp].descriptorCount = 1;
            descWrites[tmp].pBufferInfo = &bufferInfo;

            descWrites[tmp1].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
            descWrites[tmp1].dstSet = descriptorSets[j + (i * (models.size() - 1))];
            descWrites[tmp1].dstBinding = 1;
            descWrites[tmp1].dstArrayElement = 0;
            descWrites[tmp1].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
            descWrites[tmp1].descriptorCount = 1;
            descWrites[tmp1].pImageInfo = &imageInfo;

            
        }

        vkUpdateDescriptorSets(device, static_cast<uint32_t>(descWrites.size()), descWrites.data(), 0, nullptr);
    }
```

Comment: Try using `j + i*models.size()` as index for `descWrites`. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I fixed it by making a new descWrites vector inside the j loop instead of the i loop and used 0 and 1 for the indexes!

Comment: You should add this as the answer